# using $(this) inside ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(".itemInto").click(function(){
var a = $(this).siblings(".itemName").html();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {a:a},
        success: function(data) {
            alert (data); // 20     
            $(this).siblings(".itemCount").text(data);  // doesn't work. Nothing happens.

        }
    });
});
```

`.itemCount` is a sibling of `.itemInto`. Why I can't place `data` inside it? Console is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the context has changed.

Try adding `context: this` to your AJAX parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Because $(this) in callback is not $(".itemInto"),you can do like this:

```
$(".itemInto").click(function(){
var a = $(this).siblings(".itemName").html();
var $_this = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "process.php",
    data: {a:a},
    success: function(data) {
        alert (data); // 20     
        $_this.siblings(".itemCount").text(data);  // doesn't work. Nothing happens.

    }
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe you can console.log the $_this in you callback,see what will happen

Answer (score 1):

You can cache a reference to `this` as follows:

```
$(".itemInto").click(function(){
  var a = $(this).siblings(".itemName").html(),
  $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "process.php",
    data: {a:a},
    success: function(data) {
        alert (data); // 20     
        $this.siblings(".itemCount").text(data);  // use the cached variable instead.
    }
  });
});
```

Or if you *must* use `this`, you can use the native [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method as follows:

```
$(".itemInto").click(function () {
var a = $(this).siblings(".itemName").html();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "process.php",
    data: {
        a: a
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); // 20     
        $(this).siblings(".itemCount").text(data);

    }.bind(this)
  });
});
```

Comment: @bonaca How exactly is it not working? there will not be any reference issue. check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmr6soum/). anyway, check the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/xmr6soum/1/).